# Format github json data into a pandas dataframe with daily dates

Tags: json, python-3.x, pandas

I'm trying to retrieve commits for the ethereum repo from Github and format it into a DataFrame with daily dates (index) and count as the column.

I looked around but the JSON data I'm getting from Github is pretty strange to me and not exactly sure how to deal with it.

**Github JSON data:**

```
      days                  total   week
0   [0, 2, 1, 2, 2, 3, 2]   12      1515283200
1   [0, 3, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0]   5       1515888000
2   [0, 2, 6, 1, 1, 5, 0]   15      1516492800
```

**Code**

```
#Get github data
with urllib.request.urlopen('https://api.github.com/repos/ethereum/go-ethereum/stats/commit_activity') as url:
   jStr = url.read()
#Format data
data = json.loads(jStr)
data_activity = json_normalize(data)
```

**I hope to achieve:**

```
               ETH commits   
2017-11-26     2
2017-11-27     3
...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `json_normalize` to flatten the list to a new column, convert it to `DatetimeIndex` and add `timedelta`s with modulo divide by `7` to add days:

```
>>> data_activity = (json_normalize(data, 'days','week')
...                    .set_index('week').rename(columns={0:'ETH commits'}))
>>> data_activity.index = (pd.to_datetime(data_activity.index, unit='s') + 
...                        pd.to_timedelta(np.arange(len(data_activity.index)) % 7, unit='d'))
>>> print (data_activity.head(10))

            ETH commits
2018-01-07            0
2018-01-08            2
2018-01-09            1
2018-01-10            2
2018-01-11            2
2018-01-12            3
2018-01-13            2
2018-01-14            0
2018-01-15            3
2018-01-16            2
```

Comment: @wizzwizz4 - Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Here, `week` is the Unix time of the start of each week. I'm not sure how to explain this, but I'm 70% sure this code will give you the format you want:

```
import datetime

def github_norm(d):
    for week_n in range(len(d)):  # usually 52, but not guaranteed(?)
        week = d[week_n]
        week_timestamp = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(week["week"])
        for day_n, commits in enumerate(week["days"]):
            yield week_timestamp + datetime.timedelta(days=day_n), commits
```

Answer (score 0):

I implemented a date generator to make it easy.

However, I think creating df can be improved as I am not much familiar with pandas DataFrame.

```
from datetime import timedelta, date, datetime
import pandas as pd


def date_generator(first_date):
    """ given first date returns generator which yields given date and next days as date """
    yield first_date
    while True:
        first_date += timedelta(days=1)
        yield first_date


day_wise_commit_count = dict()
for week_index, week in enumerate(data):
    # print('Week ', week_index)
    f_date = datetime.utcfromtimestamp(int(week['week']))  # first date of week
    date_gen = date_generator(f_date)
    # If you are sure that list is in order you can keep above two lines out of loop
    # just use first object for first date
    for day_index, commit_count in enumerate(week["days"]):
        # print('WeekDay ', week_index, day_index)
        commit_date = next(date_gen)
        day_wise_commit_count[commit_date] = commit_count

df = pd.DataFrame(index=day_wise_commit_count.keys(), columns=['commit_count'])
for d, cc in day_wise_commit_count.items():
    df.ix[d]['commit_count'] = cc

print(df)
```